# MongoDB en el container de Ubuntu (Docker)

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

Quiero crear un contenedor de Docker donde se ejecute un archivo binario.
Estuve haciendo pruebas que las detallo a continuación.
**Mi binario DEPENDE DE QUE HAYA CONEXION A UNA BASE DE DATOS MONGO ACTIVA.**

Lo primero que hago es crear un Dockerfile.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo lo que aparece en la imagen **funciona**. Copia mi binario en ese directorio.
El tema es que en ese ubuntu no está instalado MongoDB.

Construyo la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Corro el contenedor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez dentro del contenedor, como se puede ver, se copia efectivamente el binario en la carpeta deseada y cuando lo corro me surge un error que no está corriendo mongoDB.
Tengo entendido que es porque en el sistema operativo donde estoy corriendo todo no está instalado. Pero no sé de que forma hacer para que haga todo eso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Supongo que una solución podría ser realizar un apt-install y ejecutar todos los comandos correspondientes para levantar el servidor de MONGO pero lo veo costoso e innecesario.

Comment: Y por qué no usas directamente la imagen oficial de [mongo](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo)?

Comment: es que si instalo el contenedor de mongo no sé de que forma ejecutar mi binario

Comment: La imagen oficial de mongo está sobre un ubuntu, por lo que podrás realizar tu dockerfile de igual modo, simplemente cambias el from y listo.

Comment: Gracias. Eso me funcionó. Me ayudó una compañera para ingresar a esa terminal de ubuntu que maneja mongo. Era como vos decías.

Comment: Así mismo, tengo otro problema que es que el binario se ejecuta y mongo todavía no está levantado. Habrá alguna forma de esperar a que se cargue todo lo de mongo para despues correr el binario?